# Selecting only the content between two brackets

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I PHPStore when you press ctrl+w it will selection the the content between brackets and the brackets themselves in on step. Is there any config to force it select only content without brackets?

Update: consider the following example:

```
if(true) {
    echo "Hi"; |
    echo "Bye";
}
```

The caret is at the end of the second line. Pressing `ctrl+w` triple times will select block+brackets.

Comment: Can you provide a code example and the exact caret position? When I use Ctrl + W, it first selects only the content without brackets.

Comment: @DarekKay The question has been updated.

Comment: AFAIK there is no extra settings (definitely not in Settings screen) that would allow such behaviour.